# apache not serving requests even though cpu usage is very low

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

I am working through tuning an apache server in a LAMP stack on an m3.medium ec2 instance running Amazon Linux.

Some weeks ago, mysql started crashing all the time and it seemed it was apache (2.2) causing the problem due to memory issues. We did some analysis and changed the config to much lower numbers of Servers. This resolved the mysql problem but was over xmas when there were much lower levels of traffic, we have since been gradually increasing the number of servers to try to find the optimal level for the server.

Apache is now showing an unexpected behaviour. After a certain period of time it takes ages to serve new requests (minutes), when I check top etc, when this is happening, CPU usage can be as low as 0% but is always really low, it is like apache is doing nothing. There are a bunch of apache processes in the top readout but its like they aren't doing anything. I tried turning KeepAlive off in case they were getting tied up that way but it has made no difference.

We are still using prefork MPM (in process setting up new server to change this)
config is thus

```
StartServers       10
MinSpareServers    10
MaxSpareServers   30
ServerLimit      40
MaxClients       40
MaxRequestsPerChild  2000

KeepAlive Off
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on. My undersranding of Apache is too limited to grasp what is wrong but my intuition is telling me that the apache processes are getting tied up somehow.
I've tried looking at mod_status but it won't serve it in this situation because the request sits there waiting for apache to respond.
At the moment I am having to simply regularly reset apache which is far from ideal.
I've included a bunch of monitoring oputputs below, hopefully these shed some light on what is happening or on what I should look at next.

Many thanks.

output of free:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3578       3481         96          0         22        550
-/+ buffers/cache:       2909        669
Swap:         1023        226        797
```

output of top

```
top - 10:35:15 up 12 days, 14:14,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 189 total,   1 running, 188 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3664028k total,  3559768k used,   104260k free,    21076k buffers
Swap:  1048572k total,   232500k used,   816072k free,   559268k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
19973 apache    20   0 1042m 346m 271m S  0.0  9.7   1:17.08 httpd
19964 apache    20   0 1030m 327m 266m S  0.0  9.2   1:11.35 httpd
19970 apache    20   0 1019m 316m 265m S  0.0  8.9   0:59.22 httpd
19981 apache    20   0 1034m 316m 249m S  0.0  8.8   1:10.28 httpd
19962 apache    20   0 1103m 312m 176m S  0.0  8.7   1:15.58 httpd
19966 apache    20   0 1040m 306m 233m S  0.0  8.6   1:24.83 httpd
19971 apache    20   0 1037m 304m 235m S  0.0  8.5   1:03.00 httpd
20848 apache    20   0 1023m 304m 248m S  0.0  8.5   1:11.44 httpd
19969 apache    20   0 1022m 303m 248m S  0.0  8.5   1:06.99 httpd
 2199 mysql     20   0  929m 299m 7656 S  0.0  8.4   2137:27 mysqld
27961 apache    20   0 1162m 288m 195m S  0.0  8.1   0:33.04 httpd
19968 apache    20   0 1049m 275m 194m S  0.0  7.7   1:09.61 httpd
20846 apache    20   0 1027m 272m 212m S  0.0  7.6   1:08.45 httpd
30931 apache    20   0 1062m 270m 177m S  0.0  7.6   0:21.48 httpd
21038 apache    20   0 1049m 269m 187m S  0.0  7.5   1:03.50 httpd
19984 apache    20   0 1023m 267m 211m S  0.0  7.5   1:01.80 httpd
19960 apache    20   0 1060m 259m 166m S  0.0  7.3   1:01.87 httpd
19972 apache    20   0 1025m 258m 202m S  0.0  7.2   1:01.66 httpd
19965 apache    20   0 1031m 256m 192m S  0.0  7.2   1:05.59 httpd
19963 apache    20   0 1022m 248m 192m S  0.0  6.9   0:55.78 httpd
19961 apache    20   0 1037m 247m 177m S  0.0  6.9   1:18.43 httpd
30934 apache    20   0 1019m 242m 189m S  0.0  6.8   0:07.20 httpd
30932 apache    20   0 1062m 233m 140m S  0.0  6.5   0:09.04 httpd
24211 apache    20   0 1020m 230m 177m S  0.0  6.4   0:39.03 httpd
19974 apache    20   0 1020m 227m 174m S  0.0  6.4   1:14.78 httpd
31298 apache    20   0 1015m 215m 168m S  0.0  6.0   0:05.64 httpd
  406 apache    20   0 1146m 181m  94m S  0.0  5.1   0:08.68 httpd
31297 apache    20   0 1033m 161m  96m S  0.0  4.5   0:08.05 httpd
  408 apache    20   0 1020m 139m  86m S  0.0  3.9   0:02.53 httpd
 1370 apache    20   0 1041m 136m  53m S  0.0  3.8   0:02.26 httpd
 1372 apache    20   0 1019m 125m  73m S  0.0  3.5   0:01.01 httpd
 1392 apache    20   0 1041m 111m  37m S  0.0  3.1   0:02.18 httpd
 1402 apache    20   0 1107m 100m  52m S  0.0  2.8   0:00.33 httpd
 1542 apache    20   0 1013m  97m  51m S  0.0  2.7   0:00.88 httpd
 1362 apache    20   0  999m  92m  52m S  0.0  2.6   0:01.03 httpd
 1424 apache    20   0  997m  91m  53m S  0.0  2.6   0:00.60 httpd
 1410 apache    20   0  997m  91m  53m S  0.0  2.6   0:00.38 httpd
  407 apache    20   0 1019m  91m  39m S  0.0  2.6   0:01.17 httpd
 1427 apache    20   0  997m  91m  52m S  0.0  2.6   0:00.57 httpd
 1371 apache    20   0 1013m  83m  37m S  0.0  2.3   0:00.31 httpd
 1541 apache    20   0  981m  57m  34m S  0.0  1.6   0:00.17 httpd
32187 root      20   0  967m  26m  17m S  0.0  0.7   0:02.49 httpd
```

output of sar -u

```
06:10:01 AM     all     18.23      0.00      2.03      2.42     15.23     62.09
06:20:01 AM     all     50.85      0.00      2.84      0.46     40.40      5.45
06:30:02 AM     all     48.69      0.00      2.76      0.63     38.56      9.35
06:40:01 AM     all     47.25      0.00      2.85      1.60     37.61     10.70
06:50:02 AM     all     50.16      0.00      3.52      0.57     40.73      5.03
07:00:01 AM     all     47.51      0.00      2.76      0.75     37.77     11.21
07:10:01 AM     all     35.43      0.00      2.65      1.73     28.79     31.40
07:20:02 AM     all     19.84      0.00      2.10      2.21     16.67     59.19
07:30:02 AM     all     24.34      0.00      2.30      2.28     20.17     50.91
07:40:02 AM     all     18.45      0.00      1.66      1.97     15.14     62.78
07:50:01 AM     all     22.23      0.00      2.32      2.92     18.55     53.98
08:00:02 AM     all     19.60      0.00      1.98      2.31     16.21     59.90
08:10:02 AM     all     18.17      0.00      2.00      3.72     15.07     61.04
08:20:01 AM     all     13.80      0.00      1.72      3.27     11.73     69.48
08:30:01 AM     all     11.79      0.00      1.50      3.40     10.03     73.28
08:40:01 AM     all     16.59      0.00      1.95      2.73     14.02     64.71
08:50:01 AM     all     18.04      0.00      1.96      2.37     15.26     62.38
09:00:02 AM     all     17.94      0.00      2.16      2.79     15.20     61.91
09:10:01 AM     all      4.97      0.00      0.82      1.07      4.46     88.69
09:20:01 AM     all      0.18      0.00      0.28      0.19      0.50     98.85
09:30:01 AM     all      0.13      0.00      0.19      0.05      0.41     99.21
09:40:01 AM     all      0.17      0.00      0.19      0.07      0.43     99.14
09:50:01 AM     all      0.13      0.00      0.21      0.03      0.45     99.18
10:00:02 AM     all      0.17      0.00      0.23      0.05      0.47     99.08
10:10:02 AM     all      0.14      0.00      0.20      0.04      0.44     99.18

10:10:02 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
10:20:01 AM     all      0.16      0.00      0.24      0.03      0.49     99.08
10:30:01 AM     all      0.14      0.00      0.21      0.03      0.43     99.19
Average:        all     19.78      0.03      1.78      2.19     16.21     60.01
```

output of sar -r

```
06:00:02 AM    135820   3528208     96.29    194768   1170836   2544680     54.00
06:10:01 AM    140220   3523808     96.17    196932   1174256   2531460     53.72
06:20:01 AM    133368   3530660     96.36    199088   1180468   2534200     53.77
06:30:02 AM     75624   3588404     97.94    201796   1187420   2590456     54.97
06:40:01 AM     56112   3607916     98.47    201388   1138840   2669548     56.65
06:50:02 AM     83040   3580988     97.73    195960   1120028   2659192     56.43
07:00:01 AM     56500   3607528     98.46    198812   1128004   2688464     57.05
07:10:01 AM     82508   3581520     97.75    201584   1080180   2699568     57.28
07:20:02 AM    118984   3545044     96.75    204008   1061088   2681724     56.91
07:30:02 AM     48180   3615848     98.69    206580   1053828   2757888     58.52
07:40:02 AM     98828   3565200     97.30    208404   1010216   2752216     58.40
07:50:01 AM     53364   3610664     98.54    181868    961276   2943300     62.46
08:00:02 AM     72516   3591512     98.02    132032    820096   3182764     67.54
08:10:02 AM     97400   3566628     97.34     81824    793872   3254192     69.05
08:20:01 AM    105988   3558040     97.11     77336    796660   3239836     68.75
08:30:01 AM    110324   3553704     96.99     71368    805276   3242836     68.81
08:40:01 AM     89500   3574528     97.56     79736    814620   3255128     69.07
08:50:01 AM    137284   3526744     96.25     83296    817316   3192548     67.74
09:00:02 AM     28812   3635216     99.21     62000    723488   3599616     76.38
09:10:01 AM     42524   3621504     98.84     28976    601588   3792068     80.47
09:20:01 AM     71276   3592752     98.05     25720    583384   3782844     80.27
09:30:01 AM     81648   3582380     97.77     22472    573408   3784820     80.31
09:40:01 AM     87440   3576588     97.61     21816    573048   3784832     80.31
09:50:01 AM     80876   3583152     97.79     21860    572996   3785180     80.32
10:00:02 AM     88716   3575312     97.58     22032    569412   3783548     80.29
10:10:02 AM     90332   3573696     97.53     22312    569088   3779908     80.21

10:10:02 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit
10:20:01 AM     88780   3575248     97.58     22612    567108   3783600     80.29
10:30:01 AM     90904   3573124     97.52     22932    566772   3780868     80.23
Average:       168071   3495957     95.41    129184    898526   2965883     62.94
```

UPDATE:
Really appreciate the comments and help on this. 
I'm adding more background info here:

The size of the apache processes (and hence the no. servers) is something I am questioning. 
Could large process sizes be symptomatic of a problem?
When I reduced the number of servers down to 8 the size of the apache processes went to (200Mb-400Mb) even straight after restart. When I increased to more servers then the size decreased considerably to something like (60mB)  but over time they increase in size as can be seen in the top output above.
So I am a little uncertain about no. servers - It seemed like apache was just grabbing available memory when there was a smaller no. of  servers - is that a reasonable interpretation of this?

We are running apc on some of the virtual hosts, particularly the 2 magento installs that are on the server.

I turned off KeepAlive to see if this affected the increasing process size, it didn't seem to have an effect but I have kept it off while I try to sort this out to eliminate it from the equation. We also have tried using a low value for MaxRequestsPerChild of 200 in case there was a problem there.

The server has 4G memory but as I can't work out what I think the average process size really is (because of the variability depending on the apache settings) I have adopted this, start low then increase apprach and see the free memory in free -m (looking at buffers/cache line)

thanks for the input here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an inconsistency between the `sar -u` and `top` listings.  Something not listed is using a lot of CPU.  Try changing the sort order of top to %CPU to see where the CPU is going.

It looks like you have a severe memory leak in the application you are running under apache.  Try reducing MaxRequestsPerChild to 200 or 100.  This should cause servers to be recycled before they have leaked too much memory.

Reducing MaxSpareServers to 10 or so may free up some more memory.

I use a modified log format to show the execution time for requests.  You can use the excution time field to determine if requests take too long to service.  This is the log format I use for a host with multiple virtual servers in the same log file.  The `%(ms)T` value replaces the `%l` which is always `-`. unless IdentityCheck is enabled.  (IdentityCheck relies on `ident` being enabled on the remote server, which is highly unlikely.)

```
# Modified log format with virtual host, execution time, and query params
LogFormat "%v:%p %a %{ms}T %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" local
```

Comment: thanks for reply. When I did top I used > to cycle through the CPU usage. I thought the sar -u show the same thing the top output does? At 9:10 the idle % starts ramping up to be near 100%.  I thought that was consistent with something tieing apache up but it not actually serving anything. Would you be able to help me understand why you think there is this CPU usage and what it is in the outputs that makes you think there is a memory leak. I would really appreciate that, I 'm trying to learn to interpret this data.

Comment: @Tofuwarrior  `sar` had been showing a lot of CPU used and stolen.  I would be looking at `sar -B` and/or `sar -W`, possibly `sar -q`.  It looks like you have to many large apache servers running and may be paging heavily.  Response times usually increase quickly as this kind of issue is developing. Do you have enough memory for 40 processes?

Comment: really appreciate your help. Will look int these thigns. Have added some more information to the question relating to your thoughts, especially no. servers.